# Show that $(x+1)^2 (y+1)^3 (z+1)^4 \geq 4^4$ if $xyz = 1$

Tags: inequality

Show that $(x+1)^2 (y+1)^3 (z+1)^4 \geq 4^4$ if $xyz = 1$ and $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

I have no idea whatsoever about how to even begin with it. Extraction would be too big and useless. AM-GM yields us that $f(x,y,z) \geq 4^4 x y \sqrt y z^2 \geq 4^4 \sqrt y z$. This doesn't help much as we can surely choose $y,z$ such that $\sqrt y z < 1$.

Comment: Hint: $1=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @Mindlack A stronger hint please? I appreciate that, thank you!

Comment: Second hint: $(y+1) \geq 3\left( y \times 1 \times 1\right)^{1/3}$.

Comment: Oh okay yeah, that works. I believe you are mistaken with the writing (unless further edited). basically we will consider it as $z + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \geq 4^4 \times \frac{1}{3^3} \times z$. We will get a telescoping multiplication and that will yield the desired value on the right side of the inequality

Comment: similarly $y+1 \geq 3^3 \times \frac{1}{2^2} \times y$ and $x+1 \geq 2^2 \times x$

Comment: I forgot to mention the powers on the Left Side and the comments can not be edited now. I have written the down below so that someone else doesn't spend time on this unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Just answering my question (following the hint by Mindlack) :

Using AM-GM :

\begin{align}
(x+1)^2 &\geq 2^2 x \\
(y+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2})^3 &\geq \frac{3^3}{2^2}  y\\
(z + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3})^4 &\geq \frac{4^4}{3^3} z\\
\end{align}

We get a telescoping multiplication and that proves the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM,

$$x+1=x+1\ge2\sqrt{x}$$

$$y+1=y+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac{y}{4}}$$

$$z+1=z+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\ge4\sqrt[4]{\frac{z}{27}}$$

so

$$(x+1)^2(y+1)^3(z+1)^4\ge(4x)\left(27\frac{y}{4}\right)\left(256\frac{z}{27}\right)=4^4xyz=4^4$$

as required.

Note that this is from the 2012 IMO shortlist (A3), for the special case $n=4$; the full problem is solved the same way.

Comment: I think, it's IMO 2012 exactly. See here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h488342

Comment: huh, i knew it was from a shortlist but i didn't realise it appeared on the actual imo. thanks!